# Convert lat/long to US State

Tags: java, geolocation

I have access to a list of lat/long coordinates, and I want to know (roughly) the US State these coordinates are located in. I can do with loss of precision, but I can't rely on external libraries or API. I can also add a database of locations in my code.

What is a reasonable way to do this?
I thought about 3 possibilities:

1. Represent each state by a single point at its center, then do a nearest-neighbour search
2. Represent each state by points located at cities in the state, then do a nearest-neighbour search (with much more points)
3. Represent each state by a simple bounding box, then use some algorithm to query which bounding box my point belongs to

What do you think is best? I would tend to think about solution 3, but I can't find a list of coarse "bounding boxes" for US states

Comment: You can't use external libraries  because this is a school assignment?

Comment: @NomadMaker no, more that I can't really just pull big external dependencies for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little search and find out a proper solution for what you are looking for with a dataset of bounding box.

Answer on StackOverflow: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465345/c-how-to-determine-if-a-coordinates-is-in-the-continental-united-states)

Dataset: [LINK](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml)

Algorithm to use(implement): [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon#:%7E:text=The%20idea%20of%20the%20algorithm,if%20it%27s%20odd%2C%20it%27s%20inside.)

So yes, the proper way to implement it's using the solution 3 with the given dataset.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I was struggling to find out exactly this dataset, much appreciated !

Comment: Remember that there will be always some precision errors due to the fact that the dataset can't be 100% precise

Answer (score 1):

1. Will not work, consider

[image: Proof 1]

2. Has a high likelihood to not work for at least some states. Consider states with towns/cities more clustered to the middle, against states with towns/cities clustered to the edge.

[image]

3. Will not work (these were supposed to be 90 degree angles, perfect squares, but drawing with a mouse is hard :) )

[image]

If you want to do this even vaguely accurately you will need some shape data which defines the boundaries between states. You will then need an algorithm which can determine whether a point is within an irregular polygon

See [List of the United States (US) state boundaries / borders as latitude/longitude pairs for geofence?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223270/list-of-the-united-states-us-state-boundaries-borders-as-latitude-longitude)

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed the first 2 methods are very inaccurate but they are also quite fast (at least method 1)
I will try to focus on method 3